# How to move nested links in menu edition?

Tags: 8, navigation

In Drupal 8 I created nested menu links. After some days I tried  to move them. Eg. one nested link to one parent menu link but the moving got disabled.

I remember that there were small cross icons with arrows in front of each menu link that were handles to move them before. But now they are not present. How to move the links?

There is no problem on chrome but firefox.

See the picture of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Check your console, it's likely you have javascript errors

Comment: Console is clean. But when I tested it in chrome there were no any problem there. The problem is only on Firefox. And it let me continue working that is an advantage.

Comment: Try disabling plugins (or opening a private tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have javascript error in the browser console try to click **Hide row weight** then you will see normal table drag behavior.

[image: menu items weight]